# how to get the job_id in the sun grid system using qsub

Tags: cluster-computing, sungridengine

Consider a script, "run.sh", to be sent to a cluster job queue via qsub,

```
qsub ./run.sh
```

My question is how do I get the number of the process -- the one that appears as ${PID} on the files *.o${PID} and *.e${PID} -- within the script run.sh?

Does qsub export it? On which name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently qsub man page does not have, but [this page](http://www.csp.uga.edu/resources/csp-queue-how-to) says that the variable $JOB_ID is created with the PID I was asking for.

Comment: thank you for the tips. I will test and upvote if it works :-)